# Is Archimedes' principle valid for a fluid kept in a car accelerating on a level road?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I know that it won't be valid if the fluid is accelerating in the vertical direction.

Comment: It’s valid in a frame accelerating horizontally or vertically as long as you use effective gravity in place of true gravity.

Comment: If you use a definition of "weight" in terms of support forces (something that I see in a few texts), then Archimedes' principle is true in *any* static case. Not that this saves you any work as figuring the (support-force-)weight requires exactly the same gyrations as figuring the effective gravity when using (force-of-effective-gravity-)weight.

Comment: It depends.  How would you state Archemides principle?